# Can I auto-focus a mapbox-gl react geocoder

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

We are using the [React's wrapper to Mapbox geocoder component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-map-gl-geocoder). Our code is essentially the one in the README, except that we show the geocoder entry field only on request (when clicking some "Edit Address" button).

Is it possible to auto-focus the "Search..." `<input/>` field (created by the `<Geocoder />`) component, so that a user can start typing right after the geocoder shows up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the Geocoders `onInit` prop which will be passed a gecoder instance and will be called when the geocoder has been initialized.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    viewport: {
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      latitude: 37.7577,
      longitude: -122.4376,
      zoom: 8,
    },
    searchResultLayer: null,
  };

  // rest of the code

  handleGeocoderInit = (geocoderInstance) => {
    const inputEl = geocoderInstance._inputEl;
    inputEl.focus();
  };

  render() {
    const { viewport, searchResultLayer } = this.state;

    return (
      <MapGL
        ref={this.mapRef}
        {...viewport}
        onViewportChange={this.handleViewportChange}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}>
        <Geocoder
          mapRef={this.mapRef}
          onResult={this.handleOnResult}
          onViewportChange={this.handleGeocoderViewportChange}
          mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
          position="top-left"
          onInit={this.handleGeocoderInit}
        />
        <DeckGL {...viewport} layers={[searchResultLayer]} />
      </MapGL>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```